# How to solve misspelling error in non English website to optimize SEO?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, language, spelling

I am the owner of website `pretesti.ge`. The content is not English and when I try to optimize it for SEO I come across the misspelling errors ("This page contains some spelling errors.").

1. Is there a way to ignore this errors?
2. Do these errors affect Google rankings?

My site's permalinks are set to the "post name", seems the name looks something like "**საატესტატო_გამოცდები**" do you think that it may affect too?

Comment: Where does this message come from?

Comment: @unor from a program called sitesort. I downloaded it to optimize my website's SEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tool you use is *SortSite* from *Powermapper*:

It [seems](http://www.powermapper.com/products/sortsite/checks/website-spell-checker.htm) to support English and French only:

> Spell and content checking features include:
>   · Check English and French Spelling (US, UK and international English spelling variants)

---

(If or how spelling errors may affect Google’s ranking should be a different question, as this topic is unrelated to your issue; it would also require more details about the kinds of spelling errors. So if you are interested in this, you should probably create another question.)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a "Content-Language HTTP header" so that Google does not consider this as spelling errors. If you already have this, then probably there should not be any issues with your SEO.

Comment: The [`Content-Language` HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.12) describes the natural language(s) of the _intended audience_ for the document, which is not necessarily the same as the language contained in the document. Google also [ignores all code-level language information](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html) when determining the language of a document, so it _might_ ignore the `Content-Language` header anyway. Google uses its own algorithms to determine content language.

Comment: Thanks w3d. It was a common misconception regarding that header(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157485/content-language-and-accept-language). Thanks for correcting me(http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)